# power of a matrix+induction

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $A$ the block form

$A= \begin{bmatrix}
B &C \\ 
 0&I 
\end{bmatrix}$

in which the blocks are $n \times n$. Prove that if $B-I$ is nonsingular, then, for $k \geq 1$,

$A^k = \begin{bmatrix}
B^k &(B^k-I)(B-I)^{-1}C \\ 
 0&I 
\end{bmatrix}$  (*)

---

I have tried:

Make a proof using induction

Case 1. $k=1$

$\begin{bmatrix}
B^1 &(B^1-I)(B-I)^{-1}C \\ 
 0&I 
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
B &C \\ 
 0&I 
\end{bmatrix}=A = A^1$

This is because $(B-I)$ is nonsingular, this means that it has inverse, so $(B-I)(B-I)C = IC = C$

Case 2. $k > 1$

using the Caley-Hamilton theorem applied to $A$ I know that $C_A(A) = det\begin{bmatrix}
A-B &-C \\ 
 0&A-I 
\end{bmatrix}= A^2 - A(I+B)-IB = 0$

Then $A^2 = A(I+B)-IB$, so I can say that

$A^k = A^{k-2}A^2 = A^{k-2}A(I+B)-IB$

the idea that i have is try to express (*) in this way but i don't know how

I appreciate any suggestion

Thank u

Comment: Much simpler: Just multiply it out. Cayley-Hamilton is not necessary here. Just multiply the given expression for $A^k$ by the given expression for $A$. Use basic block matrix multiplication. The just show that the expression you get is exactly what you'd expect if the assertion were true. (It is.) Make sure you do the multiplication in that order: $A^{k} A$. It works out nicely this way, but not so nicely the other way.

Comment: And you seem to have a grave misunderstanding about Cayley-Hamilton theorem. For instance, you wrote $\det\begin{bmatrix}A-B &-C \\ 0&A-I\end{bmatrix}$. How is $A-B$ a valid expression when $A,B$ have different sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would complete the induction, assuming that (*), i.e ,

$A^k = \begin{bmatrix} B^k & (B^k - I)(B -I)^{-1}C \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}, \tag{1}$

holds for some integer $k \ge 1$.  First simply form $A^{k + 1} = AA^k$ with the matrices as given, obtaining

$A^{k + 1} = AA^k = \begin{bmatrix} B & C \\ 0 & I \end {bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} B^k & (B^k - I)(B - I)^{-1}C \\ 0 & I \end {bmatrix}$
$= \begin{bmatrix} B^{k + 1} & B(B^k - I)(B - I)^{-1}C + C \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}; \tag{2}$

then observe that, for *any* matrix $B$, whether $B-I$ is invertible or not, we have

$(B - I) \sum_0^{k - 1} B^i = \sum_0^{k - 1} B^{i + 1} - \sum_0^{k - 1} B^i = B^k - I, \tag{3}$

for $k \ge 1$, whence if $(B - I)^{-1}$ exists we may write

$\sum_0^{k - 1} B^i = (B - I)^{-1}(B^k - I) = (B^k - I)(B - I)^{-1}. \tag{4}$

Using (4), we see that

$B(B^k - I)(B - I)^{-1}C + C = B(\sum_0^{k - 1} B^i)C + C = (\sum_0^{k - 1} B^{i + 1})C + C$
$= (\sum_0^k B^i)C = (B^{k + 1} - I)(B - I)^{-1}C, \tag{5}$

whence

$A^{k + 1} = \begin{bmatrix} B^{k + 1} & (B^{k + 1} - I)(B - I)^{-1}C \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}, \tag{6}$

which completes the induction and the requisite proof! ***QED.***

***Note Added in Edit; Friday 15 November 2013 9:57 PM PST:***  Scrutiny of the preceding argument reveals that the case $B - I$ *not* invertible is swiftly addressed by minor variants the above assertions.  To wit, (4) indicates that we may write

$A^k = \begin{bmatrix} B^k & (\sum_0^{k - 1} B^i)C \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}, \tag{7}$

which in fact holds for *any* $B$, also seen by an even simpler inductive step:

$A^{k + 1} = AA^k = \begin{bmatrix} B & C \\ 0 & I \end {bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} B^k & (\sum_0^{k - 1} B^i)C \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} B^{k + 1} & (\sum_0^k B^i)C \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}; \tag{8}$

the intermediate algebraic operations are contained in equation (5) above.***End:  Note Added in Edit.***

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: I really appeciate ur help, just a little question more: In the step (5) I can't see how the term $C$ at the end dissapears, I mean $(\sum_{i=0}^k B^{i+1})C + C = (\sum_0^k B^i)C$

Comment: @ LRFC:  OK, I'm baaaaack! ;-)!!!  Anyway, as I said in my previous comment, look carefully at (5) as I typed it.  The two inner equations read $B(\sum_0^{k - 1} B^i)C + C = (\sum_0^{k - 1} B^{i + 1})C + C = (\sum_0^k B^i)C$; notice that in the first equality I bumped the exponent $i$ under the summation and absorbed the leading factor of $B$ into this; then in the second equality I let $i$ drop back but bumped the upper summation limit from $k - 1$ to $k$; this maneuver kept all the previous powers of $B$ but also introduced $B^0 = I$ into the sum, ***to be continued (next comment)***

Comment: @ LRFC:  ***(continuation of previous comment)*** which in turn allowed $C = IC = B^0C$ to, as you put it, "disappear", being itself now written as part of the product $(\sum_0^k B^i)C$.  Savvy, kimo sabe?  Incidentally, your transcription of my equation into your comment contains an error which is germane to this discussion:  the left-hand side should be $(\sum_0^{k - 1} B^{i + 1})C + C$.  This may explain your question, if I am not mistaken.  Let me know if all is now clear or not!  And thanks for the +1 and of course, the "acceptance".